# How to return terminal output to a node API as JSON?

Tags: node.js, terminal

I am working on a Node API that I can use to run some commands on the Terminal.
For example, when I go to: `http://localhost:3000/runLS` the command `ls -la` is run on my working directory and the output is given back to the API as a JSON.
I have gotten as far as being able to run the terminal command from the API.
I have two code files:
commands.js which is where I have defined my commands.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { 
    console.log(stdout)
}

const runLS = (request, response) => {
    exec("ls -la", puts, (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            throw error
        }
    })
  }


  module.exports = {
    runLS
  }
```

I also have app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const port = 3000


var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true };

app.use(cors(corsOptions));


app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json({ info: 'Commandline status API ' })
})

const comm = require('./commands_test.js')
app.get('/runLS', comm.runLS)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

When I run this and then go to `http://localhost:3000/runLS` I get the stdout on the terminal. I, however, want it to appear on the browser as a JSON.
I edited my command.js file as below:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
const runLS = (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    exec("ls -la", (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            throw error
        }
        stdout.status(200).json(stdout.rows)
    })
  }


  module.exports = {
    runLS
  }
```

and then edited my app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const port = 3000


var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true };

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
)

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json({ info: 'Commandline status API ' })
})

const comm = require('./commands_test.js')
app.get('/runLS', comm.runLS)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

When I go to the endpoin now am just getting nothing, there are no errors on the terminal either. I am a Node noob so I would appreciate explanations in simple language.
Any ideas?
[If it means anything, I am working on Git Bash on windows as my terminal]

Comment: so you want the output of a command which is present on the standard output ?

Comment: yea, and it should come as a json to the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdout.rows` does not exist because it's an express response object.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
const runLS = (req, res, next) => {
    exec("ls -la", (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(400).send(error);
        }
        res.status(200).json({
            results: results
        })
    })
}


module.exports = {
    runLS
}
```